# Unable to insert text within text box using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Unable to locate text box using selenium. Error is as follows:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"proposedTagName"}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="addTagDiv" class="overlay" style="height: 50px">
    <form id="addTagForm" action="inserttag" method="post">
        <div class="floatLeft" style="margin-right: 15px">
            <table class="formTable">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td class="inputTitleCell">New Tag Name:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="proposedTagName" name="tagName" type="text" class="textInput baselineVersionInput" value="" maxlength="100"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>
        <div class="floatRight">
            <table class="formTable">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="addTagSubmitButton" class="addNewTagSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Create New Tag"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have already used: /$.driver().get().findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='proposedTagName']")).sendKeys("123");                                                                                               JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)$.driver().get();

executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('proposedTagName').value='Aman");                                                                                                                             $("proposedTagName").val("tagfittest1");

Comment: check the element is inside frame or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `driver.findElement(By.id("proposedTagName")).sendKeys("valuet");`

Something like this -

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath); //the path of chrome exe here
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        driver.get("url here");
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("proposedTagName")));
        element.sendKeys("value");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to wait sometimes before setting the value as given below.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("proposedTagName")));
element.sendKeys("valuetobesend");
```

Also, check the element is inside frame, if it is then, need to switch to the frame before.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below xpath along with expected conditions

**XPath:**

```
//table//input [@id='proposedTagName']
```

**Code:**

```
String value="XXXXX";
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//table//input[@id='proposedTagName']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//input[@id='proposedTagName']")).sendKeys(value);
```

Comment: What benefit does it add to have xath with id and not using `By.id` directly when one is available?

Comment: @eduPeeth There are so many discussions on stackoverflow about the question you are asking. Perhaps this answer was in the right direction.

Comment: @DebanjanB, Would appreciate if you could share any on this one please. I couldn't locate one in this direction.

Comment: @eduPeeth Can you can raise a ticket as per your requirement please?

Comment: @DebanjanB, I can but still not convinced that xpath with id has precedence ( benefits) over locating only with id as above. Would dig deeper. It's not the question of getting an element clicked but knowing as why would By.id won't work and xpath with id would is something I would love to see the reason for.

Comment: This solution also not working :  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function

Comment: Which driver, you are using it?

Comment: ChromeDriver version-2.38

Comment: Oh. I think, the tagName is available in id and it may result an error(Could be a driver issue). Can you change the xpath as below and then check? Xpath: //table//td/input[@class='textInput baselineVersionInput']

Comment: I think, the selenium specific keywords are used in id and name and hence you are facing the issue in chrome driver. Please try it in Firefox driver. Even in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227005/unable-to-select-value-from-select-tag-getting-exception-webdriverexception-un question also , class name has value as select.  So, I would suggest you to try with other driver, else change the xpath as //table//td/input[@class='textInput baselineVersionInput']  and then try it in chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared the element `{"method":"id","selector":"proposedTagName"}` is a `<input>` tag and you possibly need to send character sequence to the element. To achieve that you may need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//form[@id='addTagForm']//following::table[1]//input[@class='textInput baselineVersionInput' and @id='proposedTagName']"))).sendKeys("A.Prakash");
```

Comment: It is showing error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function